# Search Document Library by filename using GRAPH API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to query my Document Library in SharePoint. It just seems to return random files.

I need to search a Document Library by filename and return the files found plus a few custom columns, lets call them ColumnA and ColumnB.

My Document Library

[image]

I should mention that my site is called **test site** and my library is called **test**.

I've tried:

```
/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/search(q='name:test')

Returns:
12345
54321
```

```
/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/search(q='test')

Returns:
all files
```

```
/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/search(q='name:dummy')

Returns:
none
```

```
/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/search(q='dummy')

Returns:
dummy
```

Okay... so search doesn't do what I want as I cannot limit it to only search in the name property. Also I cannot `$expand=fields` as that'll result in `Parsing Select and Expand failed.` and I need to include ColumnA and ColumnB in the result.

So I tried

```
/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=startswith(fields/LinkFilename, 'test')

Returns
Field 'LinkFilename' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed.
```

I do not want to create indexes nor do I want to use the unsafe `Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly` header.

So I tried

```
/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields,driveItem&$filter=startswith(driveItem/name, 'test')

Returns
An unspecified error has occurred.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the filter directly to the DriveItems:

```
v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/root/children?$filter=startswith(name, 'test')
```

Since the DriveItems are exposed as ListItems in SharePoint document libraries, you can expand the ListItem property of the DriveItems:

```
v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/root/children?$filter=startswith(name, 'test')&$expand=listitem
```

I am not quite sure, what kind of data you need from the ListItem, but you can also expand the properties of the ListItem:

```
v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/root/children?$filter=startswith(name, 'test')&$expand=listitem($expand=fields)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Strange that this works when it's almost the same as `/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields,driveItem&$filter=startswith(driveItem/name, 'test')` just from a different "angle"